# Display list of most used commands

Tags: command-line, history

The command `history` will display the list of commands I used before. Now:

- How could I know the most used commands?
- Also how to count number of times I used each command?

For example:

If I use `sudo` 30 times in first day and 45 times in second day, then when displying the most used commands then `sudo` will be shown with number 75